# Complex multiplication - Ray class fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, class-field-theory

I'm pretty new to complex multiplication and am struggling with Corollary 5.20 in [Elliptic Curves with Complex Multiplication and the Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer](http://wstein.org/swc/aws/notes/files/99RubinCM.pdf) by Rubin.

According to a comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94511/understanding-the-main-theorem-of-complex-multiplication-of-elliptic-curves), we should be able to use this and know how the ray class groups are generated (torsion points). However I don't see how that is done.

I'm also not sure about the proof (which is mostly not given) and would be grateful if someone could explain it a little.

Comment: Dear Christopher, Do you understand the construction of the Hecke character $\psi$?  And do you understand the basic class field theory computations occuring in the proof?  If not, perhaps you should analyze an earlier point at which your understanding breaks down and ask about that.  But if you do, then perhaps be more precise about at exactly where your understanding of what is written in the proof breaks down.  (This argument combines a lot of what has gone before, and summarizing *all* of that would be a bit much!)  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I understand how $\psi$ was constructed and I think that (i) follows fairly quickly (for $P \in E[\mathfrak{af}]$ and $x \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{af}$ we have $[x,K^{ab}/K]P = P$ so $P \in E(K(\mathfrak{af}))$, right?) but I don't see how to prove (ii)... more importantly, though, I think, I don't understand how the result is what I want (which is a description of the ray class fields).

Comment: Is it possible to bump a question here?

Comment: I suggested Rubin's paper in MO because the OP there wanted to know the significance of the main theorem of CM. If you want to know why the ray class fields are generated by torsion points, then Silverman's "Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves" is a better, simpler reference (see Theorem 5.6 of Chapter II).